# How can I unassign a windows 7 keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I've just upgraded to Windows 7. First thing I did was install Launchy, because, well, I really love Launchy! And I always have it mapped to `WIN + SPACE` but Windows 7 mappes that to *preview desktop*. Can I somehow un-map that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to use Win+Space you could disable ALL windows key shortcuts - create and import this windows registry file (disable-win-shortcuts.reg):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoWinKeys"=dword:00000001
```

Of course that's **not always a good thing to do**, because all but Win+Space shortcuts are quite useful ... Still haven't figured out how to disable Win+Space only.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it in any clean way. Only process which requested one can release it. Since process in this case is explorer you would need to kill it. Of course, explorer will re-spawn so it is hard to make it work every time.

P.S. Do notice that hotkeys including Win key are considered to be [reserved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309(VS.85).aspx) for future use by system. If you are using one, it could get "broken" at any point in time.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to disable *all* `WIN + *` shortcut key kombinations:

1. launch `gpedit.msc` from Start menu
2. navigate in tree on the left to

   - User Configuration

     - Administrative Templates

       - Windows Components

         - Windows Explorer
3. in right pane double click "Turn off Windows+X hotkeys" (sort by column "Settings" if you are having troubles finding it)
4. in resulting dialog select *Enabled* to turn the hotkeys off.
5. reboot system

This will turn off *all* shortcut keys. So if you like `WIN+L` or `WIN+R` you are out of luck. But for me this is ok!

Comment: That does not work for *all* Win-key combinations. In Windows 7, even with the NoWinKeys registry setting, Win+P, Shift+Win+P, Ctrl+Win+P, Win+U, Win+Arrow(s), Shift+Win+Arrow(s), Ctrl+Alt+Shift+G and Win+L all continue to be reserved and work regardless, without any apparent way to disable them (or for that matter, even a way to figure out which process it is that registers them). `>:-(`